# Join nextline till the same pattern after cleaning few unwanted data

Tags: unix

Can you please help me to achieve the below output, looks like it is challenging. The data getting from one of the system is pretty not user friendly but I am trying to get into a more user friendly data. abc, def, geh,ijk (these are users) and just below that admin1, admin2 (those are the groups user belong to). As you can see there is lot of unwanted data after each group I am having difficulty in getting them aligned to line (Data for USER)

---

Data for USER 'abc'
    group1      no_body     20-Apr-2016 20:24 Regular
    group1      no_body     20-Apr-2016 20:24 Regular

Data for USER 'def'
    group3          root        22-Aug-2016 15:13 Regular

Data for USER 'ghi'
    group4         no_body     20-Apr-2016 20:24 Regular

Data for USER 'lmn'
    group1      root        24-Aug-2016 18:12 Regular
    group2      root        24-Aug-2016 18:12 Regular

Data for USER 'opq'
    DBA_Admin     user     20-Apr-2016 20:24 Regular
    dba           root        20-Apr-2016 20:24 Regular

I am looking for an output like below.

abc:group1,group2
def:group3
ghi:group4
lmn:group1,group2
opq:DBA_Admin,dba

---

If it is difficult in getting the above output atleast let me know how to eliminate anything after the group string. And by the way the Data always start with "Data for USER" if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script based on reading the file (presumably the data is in a file, if not, should be trivial to tweak this to use stdin, for example) line by line, and accumulating the user data should do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

userline=''
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ Data\ for\ USER\ \'(.*)\' ]]; then
        [ -n "$userline" ] && echo "${userline%,}"
        userline="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}:"
    elif [ -n "$line" ]; then
        userline="${userline}${line%% *},"
    else
        continue
    fi
done < data.txt

[ -n "$userline" ] && echo "${userline%,}"
```

Which produces the output:

```
$ ./script.sh 
abc:group1,group1
def:group3
ghi:group4
lmn:group1,group2
opq:DBA_Admin,dba
```

Comment: that was absolutely an awesome work my friend. Thank you sooooooo much..I was able to get the output as needed, I tested on a huge data and got good results. Thanks Again.

Comment: Can you explain me the logic used?

Comment: The core logic is pretty simple - you read the file line-by-line. If you find the  "Data for USER" string in a line, that is the start of a new line, and therefore start a new 'userline' variable. For other nonzero lines, append the first word to userline. Print the old iserline when a new one is found, and then begin the new one. Finally at the end of the main loop, print the last userline.